error in cadence virtuoso while simulation no matter what the circuit is
schematic of circuit:
using gdpk90
, 
transient analysis with stop time 5m and accuracy moderate.
error getting :
Warning from spectre during initial setup.
WARNING (CMI-2477): I0.PM0: Rds' = 70.9091 uOhm is less than 0.001. Set to 0. Notice from spectre during topology check. No DC path from node I0.net22' to ground, Gmin installed to provide path.
Warning from spectre during heuristic topology check - set topcheck=fixall to fix all floating nodes.
WARNING (SPECTRE-7): No DC path from node `I0.net23' to ground.
Circuit inventory:
nodes 9
bsim3v3 6
isource 1
vsource 3
Warning from spectre during initial setup.
WARNING (CMI-2477): I0.PM0: `Rds' = 70.9091 uOhm is less than 0.001. Set to 0.
Time for parsing: CPU = 40.994 ms, elapsed = 80.6859 ms.
Time accumulated: CPU = 2.06768 s, elapsed = 3.73958 s.
Peak resident memory used = 35.8 Mbytes.
Entering remote command mode using MPSC service (spectre, ipi, v0.0, spectre0_3307_1, ).
Warning from spectre.
WARNING (SPECTRE-16707): Only tran supports psfxl format, result of other analyses will be in psfbin format.

Transient Analysis `tran': time = (0 s -> 5 ms)

Trying homotopy = gmin' for initial conditions. Trying homotopy = source' for initial conditions.
Trying homotopy = dptran' for initial conditions........... Trying homotopy = ptran' for initial conditions..
Trying `homotopy = arclength' for initial conditions.
Error found by spectre during IC analysis, during transient analysis tran'. ERROR (SPECTRE-11005): Matrix is singular (detected at I0.net23').
ERROR (SPECTRE-16385): There were 7 attempts to find the DC solution. In some of those attempts, a signal exceeded the blowup limit of its quantity. The last signal that failed is I(V1:p) = 1.80144 GA, for which the quantity is I' and the blowup limit is (1 GA). It is possible that the circuit has no DC solution. If you really want signals this large, set the blowup' parameter of this quantity to a larger value.
ERROR (SPECTRE-16080): No DC solution found (no convergence).
The values for those nodes that did not converge on the last Newton iteration are given below.  The manner in which the convergence criteria were not satisfied is also given.
Failed test: | Value | > RelTol*Ref + AbsTol
Top 10 Solution too large Convergence failure:
V(I0.net23) = 0 V
update too large:  | -27.1776 MV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(I0.net22) = 0 V
update too large:  | 1 kV | > 0 V + 1 uV
I(V1:p) = 0 A
update too large:  | 15.9123 uA | > 0 A + 1 pA
I(V2:p) = 0 A
update too large:  | 3.97781 uA | > 0 A + 1 pA
V(I0.PM1:int_d) = 0 V
update too large:  | 185.654 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(I0.PM0:int_d) = 0 V
update too large:  | 185.654 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(I0.PM1:int_s) = 0 V
update too large:  | 185.643 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(I0.PM0:int_s) = 0 V
update too large:  | 185.643 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(out) = 0 V
update too large:  | 139.247 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
V(I0.net24) = 0 V
update too large:  | 139.247 uV | > 0 V + 1 uV
Top 10 Residue too large Convergence failure:
V(I0.PM1:int_d) = 0 V
residue too large: | -4.88057 uA | > 24.4028 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.PM0:int_d) = 0 V
residue too large: | -4.88057 uA | > 24.4028 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.net22) = 0 V
residue too large: | -1 nA | > 5.00002 pA + 1 pA
V(I0.PM1:int_s) = 0 V
residue too large: | -5.06447 uA | > 54.2318 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.PM0:int_s) = 0 V
residue too large: | -5.06447 uA | > 54.2318 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.NM1:int_s) = 0 V
residue too large: | -1.38191 uA | > 208.166 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.NM0:int_s) = 0 V
residue too large: | -1.38191 uA | > 208.166 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.NM1:int_d) = 0 V
residue too large: | 1.38191 uA | > 208.166 nA + 1 pA
V(I0.NM0:int_d) = 0 V
residue too large: | 1.38191 uA | > 208.166 nA + 1 pA
The following set of suggestions might help you avoid convergence difficulties.  After you have a solution, write it to a nodeset file by using the write' parameter, and read it back in on subsequent simulations by using the readns' parameter.

Evaluate and resolve any notice, warning, or error messages.

Perform sanity check on the parameter values by using the parameter range checker (use ``+param param-limits-file'' as a command line argument) and heed any warnings.  Print the minimum and maximum parameter value by using `info' analysis.  Ensure that the bounds given for instance, model, output, temperature-dependent, and operating-point (if possible) parameters are reasonable.

Check the direction of both independent and dependent current sources. Convergence problems might result if current sources are connected such that they force current backward through diodes.

Enable diagnostic messages by setting option `diagnose=yes'.

Small floating resistors connected to high impedance nodes can cause convergence difficulties. Avoid very small floating resistors, particularly small parasitic resistors in semiconductors. Instead, use voltage sources or iprobes to measure current.

If you have an estimate of what the solution should be, use nodeset statements or a nodeset file, and set as many nodes as possible.

Use realistic device models. Check all component parameters, particularly nonlinear device model parameters, to ensure that they are reasonable.

If simulating a bipolar analog circuit, ensure that the region parameter on all transistors and diodes is set correctly.

Loosen tolerances, particularly absolute tolerances like `iabstol' (on options statement). If tolerances are set too tight, they might preclude convergence.

Increase the value of gmin (on options statement).

Use numeric pivoting in the sparse matrix factorization by setting pivotdc=yes' (on options statement). Sometimes, it is also necessary to increase the pivot threshold to a value in the range of 0.1 to 0.5 by using pivrel' (on options statement).

Try to simplify the nonlinear component models to avoid regions that might contribute to convergence problems in the model.

Divide the circuit into smaller pieces and simulate them individually. However, ensure that the results are close to what they would be if you had simulated the whole circuit.  Use the results to generate nodesets for the whole circuit.

If all else fails, replace the DC analysis with a transient analysis and modify all the independent sources to start at zero and ramp to their DC values. Run transient analysis well beyond the time when all the sources have reached their final value (remember that transient analysis is very cheap when none of the signals in the circuit are changing) and write the final point to a nodeset file. To make transient analysis more efficient, set the integration method to backward Euler (method=euler') and loosen the local truncation error criteria by increasing lteratio', say to 50. Occasionally, this approach fails or is very slow because the circuit contains an oscillator.  Often, for finding the dc solution, the oscillation can be eliminated for by setting the minimum capacitance from each node to ground (`cmin') to a large value.


Analysis `tran' was terminated prematurely due to an error.
finalTimeOP: writing operating point information to rawfile.
Error found by spectre during DC analysis, during info `finalTimeOP'.
ERROR (SPECTRE-16041): Analysis was skipped due to inability to compute operating point.
Analysis `finalTimeOP' was terminated prematurely due to an error.
modelParameter: writing model parameter values to rawfile.
element: writing instance parameter values to rawfile.
outputParameter: writing output parameter values to rawfile.
designParamVals: writing netlist parameters to rawfile.
primitives: writing primitives to rawfile.
subckts: writing subcircuits to rawfile.

Here are some obvious errors in the schematic.

You can check and compare with this if you don't know how to fix errors above. This is just an example, not the only way to fix it. 
(Image taken from https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/12/18/3833)

